# Way to turn dates into a date range in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If you have a list of dates based on a condition ex:

```
df

date                  random_values
2020-03-01                   1
2020-03-02                   2
2020-03-03                   2
2020-04-01                   8
2020-04-02                   9 
2020-04-03                   10
2020-05-01                   7
2020-05-02                   8 
2020-05-03                   10
2020-05-04                   20
```

ex condition:
df['date'].where(df.random_values >= 8)

which would produce the following dates:

```
2020-04-01                   
2020-04-02                    
2020-04-03
2020-05-02                    
2020-05-03 
2020-05-04
```

While this amount of dates is fine for example, my data had hundreds of dates. I want to cut down the dates so it produces an output similar to this:

```
2020-04-01: 2020-04-03
2020-05-01: 2020-05-04
```

I am just trying to cut down the number of dates and make them easily into date ranges. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: I am just indexing the data to get the dates. The random_values does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this also:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

s  = df.loc[df['random_values'] >= 8, 'date']
grp = (s.diff() != pd.Timedelta(days=1)).cumsum()

s.groupby(grp).agg(lambda x: f"{x.iloc[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}: {x.iloc[-1].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}")
```

Output:

```
date
1    2020-04-01: 2020-04-03
2    2020-05-02: 2020-05-04
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `df.date` is a proper `datetime` column and you've queried your desired `dates`:

```py
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
dates = df.date.where(df.random_values >= 8)
```

You can [**`groupby(dates.dt.month)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.groupby.html) and [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) your custom output format by joining each month's first and last dates `.iloc[[0,-1]]`:

```py
dates.groupby(dates.dt.month).apply(
    lambda month: ': '.join(month.iloc[[0,-1]].astype(str)))

# date
# 4.0    2020-04-01: 2020-04-03
# 5.0    2020-05-02: 2020-05-04
# Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: good answer, just curious how iloc[-1] return last day of each month?

Comment: Thanks @Yefet. Since it's grouped by month (`.dt.month`), each group contains one month, so `iloc[0]` and `iloc[-1]` will be the first and last dates of the group (aka month).

Comment: Will this solution work if there are multiple years?

Comment: @Andrew Works fine on my end with multiple years