# How to join all unique strings from multiple columns of each group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the sample `df` below:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': ["A123", "A123", "A123"],
     'text1': ["this is a sample", "this is a sample", "this is a sample"],
     'text2': ["sing with me", "one two three", "sing with me"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I'm trying to take the id column `id` and concat the `unique` values of each of the text columns, so that the sample df:

```
id    text1              text2
A123  this is a sample   sing with me
A123  this is a sample   one two three
A123  this is a sample   sing with me
```

Will look like this:

```
id    combined_text
A123  this is a sample | sing with me | one two three
```

I tried all sort of combination of `" | ".join(x)` and `agg` and more... I can take `d['id','text1'].unique()` and `d['id','text2'].unique()` and later merge, but there must be a more efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html?highlight=stack#pandas.DataFrame.stack) and [unique()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html?highlight=unique#pandas.Series.unique) here. I also broke this up by group, using the id column.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'id': ["A123", "A123", "A123"],
     'text1': ["this is a sample", "this is a sample", "this is a sample"],
     'text 2': ["sing with me", "one two three", "sing with me"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    df.groupby('id')
      .apply(
          lambda df: ' | '.join(df[['text1', 'text 2']].stack().unique())
      ),
columns=['combined_text'])
```

Answer (score 1):

[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) and [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the `id`, then join the `set` of values:

```
(df.melt('id').groupby('id')['value']
   .agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(set(x)))
   .reset_index(name='combined_text'))
```

|  | id | combined_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A123 | one two three | sing with me | this is a sample |

---

Or if order is important, change `set(x)` to `x.unique()`:

```
(df.melt('id').groupby('id')['value']
   .agg(lambda x: ' | '.join(x.unique()))
   .reset_index(name='combined_text'))
```

|  | id | combined_text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A123 | this is a sample | sing with me | one two three |

Comment: related: [how to create a `"first date :: last date"` string per group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67041125/13138364)